# What is :>filename.txt Doing?

Tags: bash, shell, rm

```
:>filename.txt
```

For example:

```
root@box$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=1024 bs=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00536175 s, 196 MB/s
root@box$ ll
total 1024
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576 Nov 15 14:40 file.txt
root@box$ :>file.txt
root@box$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 15 14:40 file.txt
```

Is this different from an `rm`? Does it operate faster or slower than other similar means of zeroing a file or deleting it?

Comment: Related but not duplicate (missing the `:` aka `true` command):  [What does >filename.txt do in shell script](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/353149).  Surely this is a duplicate but a search for `code:":>"` didn't find anything, not even this question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you have discovered, this just empties the file contents (it truncates the file); that is different from `rm` as `rm` would actually remove the file altogether.  Additionally, `:>file.txt` will actually **create** the file if it didn't already exist.

`:` is a "do nothing command" that will exit with success and produce no output, so it's simply a short method to empty a file.  In most shells, you could simply do `>file.txt` to get the same result.  It also could be marginally faster than other methods such as `echo >file.txt` as `echo` could potentially be an external command.

Additionally, `echo >file.txt` would put a blank line in `file.txt` where `:>file.txt` would make the file have no contents whatsoever.

Comment: In `bash`, as far as I can see on the command line, you don't even have to use `:` to truncate a file, `>filename.txt` seems to be enough.  `: >filename.txt` would be portable though.

Comment: @Kusalananda `>filename.txt` is also portable, see [Shell Grammar Rules](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02). It might not work on zsh, but zsh is neither a POSIX-compliant shell nor claims to be so anyway

Comment: @oguzismail In `zsh`, `>filename` would act as `cat >filename` (unless e.g. `--emulate sh` is in effect), which means you'd be left with the shell waiting for input. `: >filename` would still work though, so that construct is _more_ portable.

Comment: Okay I got it. By *portable* I meant compatible with the standard, but I got your point now

Comment: Portability can only be seen with respect to programs that like to play in an orchestra. `zsh` does not seem to be willing to be compatible. By default, it does  not even cover the festures of a Bourne Shell from 1980.

Comment: It also creates the file if not present.

Comment: @JL2210 excellent point

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's different from `rm`.

`rm` would remove the file.

`:>filename.txt` empties the file, leaving it still there, but zero bytes in size.

Answer (score 4):

The shell invocation of `>filename.txt` redirects some output to the file "filename.txt" to completelly replace it. So, the shell has to clear all the contents of the given file before writting the output to it.

The output to be redirected is the output of the command executed. Like:

```
$ echo Hello >filename.txt
```

Will make the file of name filename.txt to contain exactly (and only) the string `Hello`.

Executing:

```
$ echo "New Value" >filename.txt
$ cat filename.txt
New Value
```

will erase everything inside the file and then write `New Value` to it.

If the command has no output, like the command `true`, the file will remain empty (truncated).

```
$ true >filename.txt
$ cat filename.txt
```

A command that is also a shell builtin is `:` (just a double dot (colon)) and that has no output. Being a builtin makes it faster than an external command such as `true` (which also has no output). So, either:

```
$ :  >  filename.txt
$ :  >filename.txt
$ :>filename.txt
```

will remove all content from the file named `filename.txt` or will create it as an empty file if it doesn't exist.

> Is this different from an rm?

That is different than a rm, as a rm will make the file disappear from `ls`, not make the file to contain 0 bytes.

> Does it operate faster or slower than other similar means of zeroing a file or deleting it?

Again, the file is not being deleted (disappear from the list given by `ls`) it transforms in an empty file (contains 0 bytes).

It should be faster than calling an external command to empty a file. Having to create a child shell to load the executable and `exec` the command makes external commands slower than the builtin `:`.

Similar solutions are (some set `$?` to 1):

```
[ ]         > filename.txt
builtin     > filename.txt
command     > filename.txt
printf ''   > filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

re: performance: this is about as efficient as possible in the shell; just asking the kernel to truncate an existing file should be more efficient than unlinking the file and re-creating a new inode with the same name.  Unless you *want* the file deleted, in which case `rm` or `unlink` it.

`:` is a shell built-in so it avoids fork/exec.  So is the equivalent `true` in normal modern shells.

`>foo` or `true > foo` gets the shell to truncate the file by making an
`open(path, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0666)` system call.

Or in practice with DASH on Linux, from the `strace sh` output:
 `openat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3`  which is equivalent.

Then it has to `close()` that FD again.  In fact, DASH doesn't special case this when you use `:>`, it jumps through the following hoops:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10          # save original stdout
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1           # redirect stdout to foo
close(3)                                = 0           # then close 3
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1           # then restore original stdout
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
```

Using `> foo` in DASH leads to the same sequence of system calls, actually redirecting fd1 and then restoring it.  I didn't check `bash` or other shells.

But that's still significantly cheaper than creating a new process to run `truncate -s 0 foo` which would (hopefully) make a single [`truncate("foo", 0)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html) which would presumably be even more efficient than an `open` + `close`.

From a language like C (or anything with system call bindings), truncating a file you don't want open can be done most efficiently with a direct `truncate` syscall.

**In Dash, `3>foo` leads to this sequence of system calls:**

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
```

Opening a new fd results in it already being fd 3, avoiding any duping.  This is the most efficient way in dash, probably saving several microseconds vs. `>foo`.  If that matters, shell scripting is the wrong language for your task!!  But you did ask.

---

With Spectre+Meltdown mitigation enabled, even a `-ENOSYS` bad system call takes at least thousands of clock cycles, so microseconds, on modern Intel x86-64.  Up from a couple hundred for the user->kernel->user round trip with just a `syscall` instruction.  Of course path lookups and so on take significant time and so does filesystem code.  And going to kernel mode and back often evicts some cache making user-space run slower upon return.

Actual I/O cost once the metadata does write-back to disk depends on the filesystem.  An FS like XFS or modern ext4 using only 1 or a few large extents for the whole file can easily free huge amounts of space in O(1) time.  Or O(n) where `n` is the number of extents (fragmentation) not the size in bytes.

Depending on the FS, if the extent info was stored right in the inode, instead of an indirect block, that's one less thing to add to the free list.

The I/O cost is similar to unlinking the file, but you don't have to free the inode or modify the directory entry.  You do still have to update the mtime and ctime in the inode upon truncation, but you had to write it anyway if the size changed.